# Stuck on understanding asyncHandler on Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am currently stuck on understanding how asyncHandler really works. I understand that asyncHandler is a wrapper method for controller methods so that we don't have to write try/catch on every method that we call on controller or services/repo (that is a good dry). I also understand that async/await returns promises so

```
return Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next)).catch(next);
```

is acting as a try/catch.
below is the full script of asynchandler

```
var asyncHandler = function (fn) {
 return function (req, res, next) {
   return Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next)).catch(next);
 };
};

module.exports = asyncHandler;
```

what I dont understand is how 
`return function(req,res,next)` 
is working?

Comment: What do you mean how it has access to those variables - what variables? You mean req, res and next? They're *arguments*, they're passed in by e.g. Express. If you mean then and catch they're *methods* on the promise.

Comment: That return statement is not executing the `function (req, res, next) { ... }`. It's returning a reference to that (anonymous) function. Some time later, the code that called the async handler to get that function reference will itself call the function and it will provide 3 parameters (req, res, next).

Comment: I am sorry, due to improper formatting I got you guys on confusion. I have corrected the question. Jarmod is that the concept of closure in js ??

Comment: See https://www.acuriousanimal.com/blog/20180315/express-async-middleware

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually comes to understanding the closure in Javascript. When you call **asyncHandler** and pass the "fn" argument to it, it actually returns a callable function that will work as a common Express controller function, therefore will have **req**, **res**, and **next** as common arguments. **asyncHandler** itself is just a function returning other function. For example

```
const controller = function(req, res, next) { 
  // do some stuff
}
counts wrappedController = asyncHander(controller)
router.use('/', wrappedController)
```

You basically wrap your **controller** function into another one, so when asyncHandler gets called it returns other common function, but saves some variables - **controller** in that case ("fn" argument), into closure.
When you trigger '/' and wrappedController gets called it just calls previously saved variable - **controller** function taking it from closure.